# telnet localhost 11211 fails. How to open the port?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, memcached, dalli

I have a server that's running memcached but it's not working. So when I try to telnet to localhost through port 11211, it fails. How would I open the port?

```
    root@s2:/usr/local/www/production/current/log# telnet localhost 11211
    Trying 127.0.1.1...
    telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused
```

Comment: firewall? memcache binding to the wrong ip?

Comment: but isn't it just connecting to itself? would the firewall still interfere? and if it did, what policy would i make? source: self, destination: self, port 11211?

Comment: Any reason your localhost is coming up as 127.0.**1**.1? Normally it's 127.0.**0**.1

Comment: I think that is the reason to my problems. I'll let you know in a few minutes when I find out

Comment: So for some reason (don't know who did it) changed localhost to point to .1.1 in /etc/hosts. I changed it back to .0.1 and it worked after that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The port is not the issue, it's the listening address.
You need to set the listen address in `memcached.conf`

`-l 0.0.0.0`  this is not safe, but the most open

or

`-l 127.0.0.1`

or the actually IP address of the host (this is what I use)

`-l 192.168.0.1`

BTW, this is my `hosts` file:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.1.1   myhostname
```